# Can this id be changed into a class so I don't have 22 of them?

Tags: css

This is my first post and I don't know how to structure the code  any differently.

First off everything displays fine and if I have 22 different ids it would validate fine too.

In my table, the column is styled by nth child to align everything centre.

If I class the TD, then the class gets overridden by the TR nth child

So I have currently this HTML

```
<td colspan="2" id="statsdiv">Total of Houses&#46;&#46;</td>
```

And this CSS

```
  #statsdiv {text-align:right;}
.table1861 tr td:first-child {
    text-align:center;
}
```

I have 355 rows in the table, and 22 need to be aligned to the right hand side. Surely I don't need to have the same ID with 22 different suffixes

Thank you

Comment: Could you provide a bit more html code? Thanks.

Comment: <tr>
   <td colspan="2" id="statsdiv">Total of Houses&#46;&#46;</td>
  <td class="statscenter">4</td>
  <td></td>
  <td colspan="4" id="statsdiv">Total of Males and Females&#46;&#46;</td>
  <td class="statscenter">10</td>
  <td class="statscenter">11</td>
  <td colspan="3"></td>
 </tr>

Comment: @AlbertMaytonn [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41983300/edit), don't post the code in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Like [Harry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983300/can-this-id-be-changed-into-a-class-so-i-dont-have-22-of-them/41983425?noredirect=1#comment71144945_41983425) mentioned in the comments

The rule

```
.table1861 tr td:first-child {
   text-align:center;
}
```

will never overwrite

```
#statsdiv {text-align:right;}
```

Cause the ID is a more specific identifier. [More details on CSS specificity can be found here](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity)

So probably you didn't show all the `ID`s and classes in your example thats why you might really face the problem you are saying in your question.

To answer the other part of your question though: Yes just adding a `class` instead of an `id` like:

```
<td colspan="2" class="align-right">Total of Houses&#46;&#46;</td>
```

should work:

```
 .table1861 tr td.align-right {text-align:right;}
```

But you might want to have a look at [calculating a selector's specificity](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity) to not run into any issues

Comment: The first part isn't correct. The `id` selector would have 100 whereas the `:first-child` has only 022 specificity but rest is correct.

Comment: @Harry thank you for your comment. What do you mean with `100` and `022`

Comment: Ooops, sorry I thought you'd know that @caramba. I was referring to the concatenated values of a-b-c that is mentioned in the specs here - https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity.

Comment: @Harry Thank you for that awesome resource! I didn't know it soo exactly how to calculate specificity.. I will update my answer

Comment: @Harry why is :first-child `022`? I just get `013`!? correct ?

Comment: Because `tr`, `td` are element selectors (so c = 2), `.table1861` is a class selector and `:first-child` is a pseudo-class (so b = 2).

Answer (score -1):

Change your ID to a class, and then in your css for the class use the !important selector after you align right, this will make it take priority.